# Using BeautifulSoup to count img tags

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I would like to count the number of dark_circle.svg and print that number. How do I accomplish this task?

**CODE:**

```
sidebar_details = SoupParser.find('div', {'class': 'sidebar-content'})
// additional working code removed
for sidebar_rows in sidebar_details.find_all("td")[::2]:
    if "Risk" in sidebar_rows:
        print (sidebar_rows.findNextSiblings())
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<td> <span><img src="/images/ratings/dark_circle.svg" width="15"/></span>
<span><img src="/images/ratings/dark_circle.svg" width="15"/></span>
<span><img src="/images/ratings/dark_circle.svg" width="15"/></span>
<span><img src="/images/ratings/dark_circle.svg" width="15"/></span>
<span><img src="/images/ratings/light_circle.svg" width="15"/></span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate `img` tag and count its instance :

```
darkcircle = 0
for i in soup.select('img'):
    if 'dark_circle' in i['src']:
        darkcircle += 1
>>> print(darkcircle)
4
```

One liner :

```
>>> sum([ 1 for i in soup.find_all('img') if 'dark_circle' in i['src']])
4
```